# Copy of Test Phase to Production Phase

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, sql-server-2012

If you have two phase, test and production phase and test phase has a database with 40 table + 55 views + all cubes from analysis service. The production phase is a reflection of test phase.

Is it possible to use powershell to make a copy of database, table, view, cubes and its data to production phase from stratch? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On technet you can find a article about how to [Move content databases in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792.aspx)

This article describes how to move content databases between servers that are running SQL Server, between instances of SQL Server, or from one SharePoint 2013 web application to another.

The article describes two ways to do this

- [Moving content databases by using Central Administration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792.aspx#proc1)
- [Moving content databases by using Windows PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792.aspx#proc2)